# Action.Submit Not firing an event / action in the server

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a problem that when creating a message on a private channel, the [Action.Submit](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html) button is not firing an event in the server whoever it works perfectly if the message is not private.

```
this.onBegin(async (session, args, next) => {
  await this.onDialogBegin(session, args, next)
});

this.onDefault(async (session) => {
  await this.onMessageReceived(session);
});
```

Chatbot private screen. The ok button not triggering an action

[image]

```
'type' => 'Action.ShowCard',
            'title' => 'Update ticket',
            'card' => [
                'type' => 'AdaptiveCard',
                'body' => [
                    [
                        'type' => 'Input.Text',
                        'id' => 'summary',
                        'value' => $this->connectWiseTicket->summary,
                        'placeholder' => 'Summary'
                    ],
                ],
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'type' => 'Action.Submit',
                        'title' => 'OK',
                        'data' => [
                            'action' => 'update_ticket',
                            'ticketID' => $ticket->id,
                            'type' => 'form_submit'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by private channel message?

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer, it's a chatbot app and it's not firing an action when the user clicks okay. Let me know if you need more context.

Comment: Guys any idea wh\y the event is not being triggered? On the other hand, where can I get docs on how to update the style UI of the chatbot? Thanks

Comment: Could you please share code for your AdaptiveCard?

Comment: I don't know if you have read https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html but that's why we are asking about the JSON for your Adaptive Card. I suspect that's what the problem is that the `data` object may not be properly formatted.

Comment: Thank you, I just added the JSON.

Comment: @MichelArteta- Could you please share the final JSON string after replacing actual values for variables($this->connectWiseTicket->summary)? Or may be just try the [sample JSON shared here](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html) .
Or Try this: 
      **"data": {
        "action": "update_ticket",
        "ticketID": "TestId",
        "type": "form_submit"
      }**